# Is this how the size() function really works in std::string?

Tags: c++

I wrote a simple function that can get the size of a `std::string` class object, and I know that `size()` function in `std::string` does the same job, So I wanted to know if the `size()` function *really* works like my function or if it is more complicated? If it's more complicated, then how?

```
int sizeOfString(const string str) {
    int i=0;
    while (str[i] != '\0') {
        ++i;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An `std::string` can contain null bytes, so your `sizeOfString()` function will produce a different result on the following input:

```
std::string evil("abc\0def", 7);
```

As for your other question: the `size()` method simply reads out an internal size field, so it is always constant time, while yours is linear in the size of the string.

You can peek at the implementation of `std::string::size` for various implementations for yourself: [libc++](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/libcxx/include/string#L949-L950), [MSVC](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/master/stl/inc/xstring#L1239-L1241), [libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h#L901-L902).

Comment: By "internal size field" you mean `sizeof(str) / sizeof(str[0])` or something like that?

Comment: No, the `std::string` object has an actual `_size` field that contains the size of the string. See the links I posted for the various implementations.

Answer (score 4):

No.

Firstly, a `std::string` can contain `NUL` characters that count as part of the length, so you can't use `'\0'` as a sentinal, in the way you would for C-strings.

Secondly, The Standard guarantees that `std::string::size` has **constant** complexity.

In practice there are a few slightly different ways to represent a `std::string`:

1. pointer to start of buffer, buffer size, length of current data - [`size()` just has to return the length member.](https://github.com/bloomberg/bde/blob/master/groups/bsl/bslstl/bslstl_string.h#L5261)
2. pointer to start of buffer, pointer to end of current data, pointer to end of buffer - `size()` has to return a simple calculation.

Answer (score 1):

It is different than your implementation.

Your function iterates over the string until it find a null byte. Null terminated string are how string are handled in C through `char*`. In C++ a string is a full object with member variables.

Specifically for C++, the size of the string is stored as part of the object, making the `size()` function simply read out the value of a variable.

For a interesting talk about how a string works in C++ check out this video from CppCon: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPR8h4-qZdk

Answer (score 0):

No. Not at all like that.

std::string actually maintains the size as one of its data member. Think of std::string as a container that keeps a pointer to the actual data(a char*) and length of that data separate.
When you call size(), it actually just returns this size, hence it's `O(1)`.

One example to highlight it's effect in practicality will be

```
// WRONG IMPLEMENTATION
int wrongChangeLengthToZero(std::string& s)
{
    assert(s.size() != 0);
    s[0]='\';
    return s.size(); // Won't return 0
}
// CORRECT
int correctChangeLengthToZero(std::string& s)
{
    assert(s.size() != 0);
    s.resize(0);
    return s.size(); // Will return 0
}
```